Does the Anscombe-Aumann independence condition imply Savage's P4 axiom (Comparative Probability)?
Does the Anscombe-Aumann independence condition imply Savage's P4 axiom (Comparative Probability)?
Formal Definitions

Anscombe-Aumann Independence Condition:
For all acts $f$, $g$, $h$ and $\alpha \in (0, 1)$,
$$f \succcurlyeq g \iff \alpha f + (1-\alpha)h \succcurlyeq \alpha g + (1-\alpha)h$$

Savage's P4 Axiom (Comparative Probability):
For all events $A$ and $B$, and outcomes $x^* \succ x$ and $y^* \succ y$:
$$x^*_A x \succcurlyeq x^*_B x \iff y^*_A y \succcurlyeq y^*_B y$$
Where $x^*_A x$ denotes the act that yields $x^*$ if event $A$ occurs and $x$ otherwise.


Attempt
Step 1: Assume the independence condition holds.
Step 2: Consider events $A$ and $B$, and outcomes $x^* \succ x$ and $y^* \succ y$ as in Savage's P4.
Step 3: Define the following acts:
$$\begin{align*}
   f &= x^*_A x \\
   g &= x^*_B x \\
   h_1 &= y^*_A y \\
   h_2 &= y^*_B y
   \end{align*}$$
Step 4: By the Anscombe-Aumann independence condition, for any $\alpha \in (0, 1)$:
$$f \succcurlyeq g \iff \alpha f + (1-\alpha)h_1 \succcurlyeq \alpha g + (1-\alpha)h_1 \tag{1}$$
Step 5: Observe that:
$$\begin{align*}
   \alpha f + (1-\alpha)h_1 &= (\alpha x^* + (1-\alpha)y^*)_A (\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y) \\
   \alpha g + (1-\alpha)h_1 &= (\alpha x^* + (1-\alpha)y^*)_B (\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y)
   \end{align*}$$
Step 6: Define $z^* = \alpha x^* + (1-\alpha)y^*$ and $z = \alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$. Note that $z^* \succ z$ because $x^* \succ x$ and $y^* \succ y$.
Step 7: Equation (1) can now be written as:
$$f \succcurlyeq g \iff z^*_A z \succcurlyeq z^*_B z \tag{2}$$
Step 8: Similarly, we can apply the independence condition to $h_1$ and $h_2$:
$$h_1 \succcurlyeq h_2 \iff \alpha h_1 + (1-\alpha)f \succcurlyeq \alpha h_2 + (1-\alpha)f \tag{3}$$
Step 9: Observe that:
$$\begin{align*}
   \alpha h_1 + (1-\alpha)f &= (\alpha y^* + (1-\alpha)x^*)_A (\alpha y + (1-\alpha)x) \\
   \alpha h_2 + (1-\alpha)f &= (\alpha y^* + (1-\alpha)x^*)_B (\alpha y + (1-\alpha)x)
   \end{align*}$$
Step 10: Define $w^* = \alpha y^* + (1-\alpha)x^*$ and $w = \alpha y + (1-\alpha)x$. Note that $w^* \succ w$.
Step 11: Equation (3) can now be written as:
$$h_1 \succcurlyeq h_2 \iff w^*_A w \succcurlyeq w^*_B w \tag{4}$$
Step 12: From (2) and (4), we have:
$$\begin{align*}
   f \succcurlyeq g &\iff z^*_A z \succcurlyeq z^*_B z \\
   h_1 \succcurlyeq h_2 &\iff w^*_A w \succcurlyeq w^*_B w
   \end{align*}$$
Step 13: Since $z^* \succ z$ and $w^* \succ w$ are arbitrary pairs of outcomes with the better outcome associated with the event, we are getting close to the Savage's P4 axiom...
Am I on the right track?
